# Is $\beta \in [\beta_1,\beta_2]$ when $Y=\beta X+\theta Z+\epsilon$ and $Y=\beta_1 d X+\beta_2 (1-d)X+\theta' Z+\varepsilon$ where $d$ is dummy

Tags: regression, least-squares

As is clear from the title, the question concerns what happens when finer categories are introduced in a regression. For example, suppose we want to analyze the effect of height on income comparing men and women using the regression $\text{Income}=\beta \text{Male} \times \text{Height}+\theta \text{Height}+\zeta \text{Male}$. Now, suppose you further split men into white and non-white and run the following regression
$$\text{Income}=\beta_1 \text{White Male} \times \text{Height}+\beta_2 \text{Non-White Male} \times \text{Height}+\theta'\text{Height}+\zeta' \text{Male}$$
Then, is it always the case that
$$\min(\beta_1,\beta_2)\leq\beta \leq \max(\beta_1,\beta_2)$$
?

Comment: Please review our posts about [Simpson's Paradox](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=Simpson%27s+paradox).